# Select entry from any locale with Entries Field

Tags: entries, localization, entries-field

I'd like to be able to create an Entries field that can select from entries from all locales.

Currently it looks like there's the option to choose a single locale or specify the same locale as the source entry.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way around this?

Not that I'm aware of.  You can currently only select entries from the locale you're viewing (same as source), or an explicit one specified in the settings.

You can't browse across multiple locales and select entries.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Matrix and have one Block Type with an entries field for each of your locales.